# Python Selenium Scraper error - ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, selenium, csv, web-scraping

I am trying to run the following python code

Technology: Python, Selenium scraper
Device: Windows device

Getting error......

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "scraper.py", line 35, in for row in cp_url: 
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# Description: The Python code below will search selenium in Google.
import time
import csv
import os


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#EVERYTIME CHANGE THE DRIVER PATH TO THE CHROME DRIVER FOR LATEST CHROME VERSION
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path="D:\chromedriver.exe")

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

contents = []

filePath = 'output1.csv'
# As file at filePath is deleted now, so we should check if file
# exists or not not before deleting them
if os.path.exists(filePath):
    os.remove(filePath)
else:
    print("Can not delete the file as it doesn't exists")

f = open("output1.csv", "a")
f.write("website," + "htmltag," + "type," + "id," + "classname," + "for," + "href," + "alt," + "type," + "src,"
+ "name," + "width," + "height," + "data-src,"+ 'inner-text,' + 'action,' + 'value,' + "\n")


with open('inputLinks1.csv', 'rt') as cp_csv:
 cp_url = csv.reader(cp_csv)
for row in cp_url:
        links = row[0]
        contents.append(links)
        driver.get(links)
        with open('xpathtags.csv', 'rt') as cp2_csv:
            cp_url2 = csv.reader(cp2_csv)
            for row1 in cp_url2:
                print(row[0])
                (xtype, xpathtext) = row1[0].split(';') 
                print(xtype, xpathtext)
                contents.append(xtype)
                contents.append(xpathtext)
                elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpathtext)
                for elem in elems:
                    f = open('output1.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
                    f.write( links + ", "+ xtype + "," 
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('type')) + ', '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('id')) + ', '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('class')) + ', '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('for')) + ', '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('href')) + ', '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('alt')) + ', '                        
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('type')) + ', '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('src')) + ', '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('name')) + ', '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('width')) + ', '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('height')) + ', '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('data-src')) + ', '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('innerText').strip()) + ', '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('action')) + ', '
                         + str(elem.get_attribute('value')) + ', '

                        + '\n')
                   
                    f.close()  


driver.close()
```

I am using the following CSV files

A) inputlinks1.csv

```
www.flipkart.com
www.ebay.com
```

B) xpathtags.csv

```
Link;//a[@href]
Button;//button
Image;//img
Heading1;//h1
Heading2;//h2
Heading3;//h3
Heading4;//h4
```

C) `Output.csv` is a blank file

I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 35, in <module>
    for row in cp_url:
  ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: You have a snytax error on that line, are you using the correct spacing and not interchanging spaces / tabs?

Comment: spacing is correct only . Can you please guide ?

Comment: Try changing `with open('inputLinks1.csv', 'rt') as cp_csv:` to `with open('inputLinks1.csv', 'r') as cp_csv:`

Comment: Thanks Kamalesh.I am still getting the same error after changing.

Comment: is this full error message? Always show full traceback. Stackoverflow doesn't show line numbers - which line is 35?

Comment: I see one problem - you have wrong indentations. You run `for row in cp_url:` outside `with open('inputLinks1.csv', 'rt') as cp_csv:` - which automatically close file - so you run it after closing this file.  And this can be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it but I think your problem is that you have wrong indentations

```py
with open('inputLinks1.csv', 'rt') as cp_csv:
 cp_url = csv.reader(cp_csv)
for row in cp_url:
    # ...rest...
```

so you run `for`-loop outside `with...as...` and `with...as...` automatically closes file.

You should run `for`-loop inside `with...as...`

```
with open('inputLinks1.csv', 'rt') as cp_csv:
    cp_url = csv.reader(cp_csv)
    for row in cp_url:
        # ...rest...
```

Or you could use standard `open()` and `close()`

```
cp_csv = open('inputLinks1.csv', 'rt')

cp_url = csv.reader(cp_csv)
for row in cp_url:
    # ...rest...

cp_csv.close()
```

Comment: I should have refreshed my page, while testing the code :(, came up with the same solution.

Comment: @KamaleshS sometimes it happens to me too. I start creating solution and meanwhile someone else create answer. You added information about other problems so your answer is also useful

Comment: Yeah, agreed !!

Answer (score 1):

Had to make a few changes to your code to get it working.

After fixing indentation, it threw another error w.r.t `inputlinks1.csv` file.
Changed it to-

```
https://www.flipkart.com
https://www.ebay.com
```

And always try to use `with open` when handling files.

Code snippet:-

```
contents = []

filePath = 'output1.csv'
# As file at filePath is deleted now, so we should check if file
# exists or not not before deleting them
if os.path.exists(filePath):
    os.remove(filePath)
else:
    print("Can not delete the file as it doesn't exists")

with open("output1.csv", "a") as f:
    f.write("website," + "htmltag," + "type," + "id," + "classname," + "for," + "href," + "alt," + "type," + "src,"
    + "name," + "width," + "height," + "data-src,"+ 'inner-text,' + 'action,' + 'value,' + "\n")

with open('inputLinks1.csv', 'r') as cp_csv:
    cp_url = csv.reader(cp_csv)
    for row in cp_url:
            links = row[0]
            print(links)
            contents.append(links)
            driver.get(links)
            with open('xpathtags.csv', 'r') as cp2_csv:
                cp_url2 = csv.reader(cp2_csv)
                for row1 in cp_url2:
                    print(row[0])
                    (xtype, xpathtext) = row1[0].split(';') 
                    print(xtype, xpathtext)
                    contents.append(xtype)
                    contents.append(xpathtext)
                    elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpathtext)
                    for elem in elems:
                        with open('output1.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                            f.write( links + ", "+ xtype + "," 
                            + str(elem.get_attribute('type')) + ', '
                            + str(elem.get_attribute('id')) + ', '
                            + str(elem.get_attribute('class')) + ', '
                            + str(elem.get_attribute('for')) + ', '
                            + str(elem.get_attribute('href')) + ', '
                            + str(elem.get_attribute('alt')) + ', '                        
                            + str(elem.get_attribute('type')) + ', '
                            + str(elem.get_attribute('src')) + ', '
                            + str(elem.get_attribute('name')) + ', '
                            + str(elem.get_attribute('width')) + ', '
                            + str(elem.get_attribute('height')) + ', '
                            + str(elem.get_attribute('data-src')) + ', '
                            + str(elem.get_attribute('innerText').strip()) + ', '
                            + str(elem.get_attribute('action')) + ', '
                            + str(elem.get_attribute('value')) + ', '

                            + '\n')
                   

driver.close()
```